# How to make sure that applying a function to each row with "apply", the result is put together in a row-wise manner?

Tags: r, dataframe

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

and I apply some function to each row

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x))
```

How can I make sure that the results are combined row-wise? I would like to have a data frame/vector again where each row contains the according sum. This is a rather simple example but I hope it illustrates the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could do it. The following way is one of them:

```
t(apply(df, 1, function(x){c(x,sum(x))} ))
```

**UPDATE:**

if the result of function returns a df:(I have assumed a fn that returns a df that with 2 rows: row1- data row with sum at the end & row2- repeat row 1

```
interim_res<- rbind(lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(x){
as.data.frame(rbind(c(x,sum(x)),c(x,sum(x))))
}))
res<- do.call(rbind,interim_res)
```

Comment: @ Anurag Priyadarshi. Thanks for your answer. However, it doesn't quite work for me. The problem is that my function creates a data frame for each row (due to some kind of simulation) and what I want is to eventually bind them row-wise. Sorry for the not clearly formulated question.

Comment: @PatrickBalada . updated my answer. I went through apply doc. There are restrictions on what apply can return. So, I have chucked apply and used lapply as it return a list. This works, but I hope somebody gives an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I think `sapply`will simplify multiple `data.frame` by `rbind`-ing them so you could try

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
sapply(t(df), function(x), sum(x))
```

Or at least it will put them in a list which you could then `rbind`